# Need help I have the 3com 48port network switch

Tags: networking

Hello I have the 3Com 4800G 3CRS48G and I am trying to use the console port on it but I can't find any software that I can use to be able to control each port on it like to set priorities find out what is taking up a lot of bandwidth etc.

Also I have a windows 10 computer if that matters

If anyone can help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [putty](https://www.putty.org/), telnet or hyperterm for a serial communication. (COM1-4)

After if not used to configure the switch that way, configure the IP, and login via the web browser after;

> Step 1: Log in to the switch through the console port and assign an IP
>   address to the management VLAN interface of the switch. By default,
>   VLAN 1 is the management VLAN.
>
> Connect to the console port. Refer to
>   section “Setting Up the Connection to the Console Port” on page
>   31.
>
> Execute the following commands in the terminal window to assign an IP address to the management VLAN interface of the switch.
>   Configure
>   the IP address of the management VLAN interface to be 10.153.17.82
>   with the mask 255.255.255.0.
>
> `<SW4800G> system-view`
>
> `[SW4800G] interface vlan-interface 1`
>
> `[SW4800G-Vlan-interface1] ip address 10.153.17.82 255.255.255.0`
>
> Step 2: Configure the user name and the password for the Web-based network management system.
>
> Configure the user name to be admin.
>
> `[SW4800G] local-user admin`
>
> Set the user level to level 3.
>
> `[SW4800G-luser-admin] service-type telnet level 3`
>
> # Set the password to admin.
>
> `[SW4800G-luser-admin] password simple admin`
>
> Step 3: Establish an HTTP connection between your PC and
>   the switch, as shown in the following figure

Comment: also I hope not but I am pretty sure do I need to get a console cord the RJ45 to USB or the RJ45 to DB9 cord or can I just use RJ45 TO RJ45 to connect to the network switch.

Comment: @glennhull By console you need the serial connector, it’s rare non to see them on laptop, as such I suggest a USB to serial adaptor.

Comment: Okay thanks Yagmoth555